# Laravel 5.1 application deployment

Tags: laravel-5.1, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I have developed an application with Laravel5.1. Now I need hosting suggestion for deploying my application. I know it's a silly question but I want a reliable answer. Before buying a hosting I want to know which hosting service will provide proper environment to run a laravel5.1 application.
Php version required >= 5.5.9

Answer (score 0):

This is such a hard question to answer as it all depends on what you're after.

Some questions to consider:

- Do you want to set the server up yourself?

If this is the case then any unmanaged provider will do the trick, you'll just need to set it all up; LAMP, Git, Composer etc.

- Do you want to manage the server itself but you aren't sure how to set it up?

[Digital Ocean](https://m.do.co/c/8b9f6e30f90b) (and other providers I'm sure) offer one-click apps where you can deploy whatever you want. For Laravel you would probably want to pick the LAMP app install. These deploy all the packages you will require and set them up for you so that you don't need to - the rest of the server management would be up to you from there.

- Do you want to use Managed Hosting where they do it all for you?

[OVH](https://www.ovh.com/us/) have been pretty good for me in the past, I've never used their managed option, although I know they have it - and I've had great service from them too.

If you're still not sure then I would suggest looking for a provider that provides servers that come with a LAMP stack (as this covers everything you need for Laravel) or one that supports PHP applications - if you're not sure then just contact the company and ask. Or find someone (a friend or a professional) who can help you get started online.

Comment: I want a managed hosting just like godady or hostgator. Where all I'll be needed is to copy the files in the server's root folder.

Comment: Then talk to them about getting an environment set-up to do this... As you just need a host that provides the requirements for Laravel; PHP >= 5.5.9, OpenSSL PHP extension, PDO PHP extension, Mbsting PHP extension, and Tokenizer PHP extension.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion because you are using Laravel is to look at https://forge.laravel.com/ where you can handle servers that runs in Digital Ocean and other providers.

Fits perfectly for Laravel.